# No matching client found for package name processAppDebugGoogleServices

Tags: android, android-productflavors, google-play-services

I have tried almost every related solution present on Stack Overflow.
But the problem is still unsolved.

```
Error: Execution failed for task ':App:processAppDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.application'
```

Setting.gradle:

```
include ':App'
```

Here is the manifest code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.application"
    android:versionCode="17"
    android:versionName="1.17">
```

Here are the application level Gradle dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

**Problem**: flavor1, that is the application, is generating the error whereas application_rtl is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some issue with the build file or project configuration.

The problem is solved now, maybe because I have updated from Android Studio 1.5.1 to Android Studio 2.0.

Here are some other changes for application level Gradle dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

Comment: does this mean that your app will not be compatible with any android API version less than 23? so devices running 5.0 and earlier are a no go?

Comment: i am sorry but i am a continuos learner and that answer is old. i have edited the answer

Comment: there is nothing related to build version and compile sdk. the problem was due to gradle version and google service dependency

Answer (score 5):

The 'No matching client found ...' message can be generated if the app uses Google Services but the 'google-services.json' file is not configured properly for the app's applicationId (packageName).

Verify that your project has a 'google-services.json' file which contains an 'android_client_info' block with a 'package_name' of 'com.example.application'.

Look for a block that looks like this:

```js
"client_info": {
     "mobilesdk_app_id":"1:12345678901:android:876a5bc432109d87”, 
     "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.application”
     }
}
```

and verify that it's correct. Probably the best thing to do is just generate a new, correct google-services.json file from the Firebase console.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: I had this problem after renaming the main package. Updating the google-services.json fixed it.